# Bus error when try to change a variable value

Tags: c

I created a variable and assign with some value.
When I call a function and try to change the value of variable I received a bus error.

If I use malloc, works.

My question is:

Why isn't working without malloc?

cause I think in theory, when you create a variable you automatically have a memory address (printf("%p") prove that) and you can access that variable values, so memory already are allocated and being used.

So why you can't change without bus error?

thats my code

```
void    strclr(char *s)
{
   printf("%s \n", s);
    while(*s)
    {
        *s = '\0';
        s++;
    }
    printf("%s ok", s);
}

int main()
{

    char *str = strdup("testing"); //allocate with malloc
    char *str2 = "testing";

    strclr(str); //works
    strclr(str2); //don't work, bus error;
}
```

Comment: pastebin code: https://pastebin.com/7qUaXTJx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str2` is pointing to a **string literal**.  These are is read only, and in fact are typically placed in a read-only section of memory.   That's why you get a bus error when you try to modify it.

If you define `str2` as an array you'll be able to modify it.

```
char str2[] = "testing";
```

Here, we have an array which is *initialized* with a string literal.  It is not a string literal itself.